# Declaring Arrays of Objects within another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have recently gotten into javascript (about four days ago), and I'm having troubles acclimating to the syntax a little bit. I'm creating a calender of sorts and I'm trying to get an array of objects (one for each month) to be declared within my "main" object, the calender. I have done copious amounts of googling and browsed all over W3Schools and can't seem to figure it out. So if I have

```
var calender = {
:
:...functions{},
months: [],
```

How would I go about getting objects inside of `months` and declaring their properties (i.e. `months[0]` would have a name of "January" and its number of days etc)? I am at a conceptual standstill. Do I accomplish this index by index, or can I just literally declare the objects at array creation? From what I grasped so far, it would seem normally I could just say something like `var arr = {varName: "name",...(and so on)}`, but it seems doing that in the brackets is not allowed, and I'm not sure syntactically where I access the indices. Or maybe I'm just doing this utterly bass ackwards. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way; object literals within an array:

```
var calendar = {

    months: [
        {
            name : "Jan",
            days : 31
        },
        {
            name : "Feb",
            days : "28ish"
        }  
    ]
};

alert( calendar.months[0].days );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you. So basically the indices serve as the `var` name in a sense? Or is it bad to view it in that way?

Comment: Best to view them as key/value pairs. `calendar` has one key `month` that has an array as its value. In turn that array has two objects each of which have `name` and `days` values.

Comment: Kind of, (IMO) you should think of an Array (months) as a *single entity* (a variable, or in the example above the property of an object) that is a list containing values that are stored & accessed by a numeric index

Comment: Thank you both, having a conceptual understanding helps a great deal. Coming from other OOPs that I am also learning, its good to understand the distinctions. Appreciate your time =)

Answer (score 1):

Let's get back to basics, this is how you can write literal objects, arrays and objects containing arrays containing objects that contain arrays:

```
var my_object = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
console.log(my_object.key1);

var my_array = ["value1", "value2"];
console.log(my_array[0]);

var my_compound = {a: [{b: "c", d: [0, 1, 2]},
                       {b: "e", d: [3, 4, 5]}]};
console.log(my_compound.a[1].d[0]);  // => 3
console.log(my_compound["a"][1]["d"][0]);  // same thing, perhaps more readable?
```